# Characterization of Authors Addresses

Tags: author

My article has three authors. I have used following codes:

‎‎

```
‎‎\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

 ‎\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
 ‎\usepackage{graphicx}‎‎‎
‎

‎\newcommand{\address}{Department of Statistics‎, ‎University a, London‎‎‎‎‎.} ‎‎‎‎
\newcommand{\addresss}{Department of Statistics‎, ‎Faculty of Mathematical science‎, ‎University b‎, ‎Germany‎‎}‎
‎\newcommand{\email}{Email‎: ‎john1999@gmail.com}‎‎
‎\title{Sample Size }‎
‎\author[1]{M. Xu‎‎‎} \author[1]{H. Tim\footnote{Corresponding author‎. ‎\\ \email‎}‎} ‎\author[‎2‎‎ ]‎{D‎. Minay ‎‎‎}‎‎
‎\affil[1]{University a}‎
 \affil[2]{‎‎‎‎‎‎University b}‎‎‎‎  
‎\date{}‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\maketitle‎
‎\address‎‎ ‎\\‎
\addresss
‎\end{document}‎
```

Then, the first page of my paper is as following picture:
[image]

How can one set "University a" and "University b" in one line? Is it possible to characterize address of each author without using `\footnote`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I can see, printing the affiliations in separate lines in hardcoded in `authblk` and changing this requires a good deal of work.